# Update search page by using the enter key instead of clicking a link

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I have a section for users to use three different filters to search a database for tips that have been inputted.  I currently have a button that calls a javascript function that pulls the information and displays it in the correct div.  It works the way I want it to, but since I am not using a form, I must click the ‘update’ button in order to refresh the results div instead of being able to hit enter on the keyboard.  I want to be able to use the enter key to update the results, but I do not want to refresh the page with post or get data.  The user needs to be able to use the back key to get to the previous page.  I am just learning javascript so I’m not sure the best way to do this.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(function() 
    {
        $("#category").change(function() 
        {
            $("#systemType").load("/tech/tips/_inc/tech_tip_find_system.php?category=" + $("#category").val());
        });
    }); 

    function searchTips()
    {
        $("#showTips").load("/tech/tips/_inc/search_tips.php?category=" + $("#category").val() + "&system=" + $("#system").val() + "&search=" + $("#search").val());
    }
</script>

<div class="filterTips">
    <h4>Filters:</h4>
    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="all">All Categories</option>
        <option value="phones">Phones</option>
        <option value="bells">Bells/Clocks</option>
        <option value="security">Security</option>
        <option value="tpac">Telepacific</option>
    </select>
    <div id="systemType"><input type="text" id="system" name="system" readonly="readonly" /></div>
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search Tech Tips" />
    <button onclick="searchTips()">Update</button>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>  
<div class="showTips" id="showTips">
    <?php include '_inc/search_tips.php'; ?>
</div>
<div class="filterTips"><br />&nbsp;</div>
```

I know I should be using a form with the select and input tags but having the page re-load is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use ajax for getting records without refreshing the page.. and I here is the answer for pressing enter button:

```
$( "#search" ).keypress(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
      $("#showTips").load("/tech/tips/_inc/search_tips.php?category=" + $("#category").val() + "&system=" + $("#system").val() + "&search=" + $("#search").val());
  }});
```

Here is the example for ajax :
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$( "#search" ).keypress(function( event ) {
    url = "/tech/tips/_inc/search_tips.php?category=" + $("#category").val() + "&system=" + $("#system").val() + "&search=" + $("#search").val() ;
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
    $.post( url, function( data ) {
      $( "#showTips" ).html( data );
    });
    }
});
```